# Difference in Perl regex variable $+{name} and $-{name}

Tags: regex, perl

What is the difference between Perl regex variables `$+{name}` and `$-{name}` when both are used to refer to the same regex group from Perl statement/expression code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While `$+{name}` holds the captured substring referred by `name`
as a scalar value, `$-{name}` refers to an *array* which holds capture
groups with the name.
Here is a tiny example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

'12' =~ /(?<foo>\d)(?<foo>\d)/; # '1' and '2' will be captured individually

print $+{'foo'}, "\n";          # prints '1'

for (@{$-{'foo'}}) {            # $-{'foo'} is a reference to an array
    print $_, "\n";             # prints '1' and '2'
}
```

As `$+{name}` can hold only a single scalar value, it is assigned
to the first (leftmost) element of the capture groups.

Comment: no way for get in relative way ?
e.g to refer to get the last group from Perl code inserted inside regex.

Comment: Could you illustrate your requirement with some example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763984/refer-or-to-get-the-last-regex-group-from-perl-code-insertion