# How to refer to the last capture group inside Perl code embedded in regex via (?{...})?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

I would like to be able to use the last capture group in the Perl code embedded via `(?{...})`

```
'foobar' =~ /(oo)(bar)(?{ $word = ${-1} })/
```

My attempt above fails. I want the variable `$word` to have the string `bar` after the regex.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like:

```
my $word = 'var';
my @match = 'foobar' =~ /(oo)(bar)/;
$word = $match[-1];
print $word, "\n";
```

Output:

```
bar
```

**[EDIT]**
By using the named captures, you can say:

```
my $word = "var";
'foobar' =~ /(?<g>oo)(?<g>bar)(?{$word=${$-{'g'}}[-1]})/;
print $word, "\n";
=> bar
```

If your perl version is 5.25 or newer, which supports the special variable `@{^CAPTURE}`, following code may work (not tested).

```
'foobar' =~ /(oo)(bar)(?{$word=${^CAPTURE}[-1]})/;
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, which may be closer to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Can use the [$+ variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$LAST_PAREN_MATCH)

> The text matched by the highest used capture group of the last successful search pattern. It is logically equivalent to the highest numbered capture variable ($1, $2, ...) which has a defined value.

Example:

```
perl -wE'$v = shift // q(aabb); $v =~ /(a)(b)(?{ $m = $+ })/; say $m'    #--> b
```

This works as expected with nested captures as well, so with `(a(b))` the `$+` has `b`.

Also see a similar but "*subtly different*"  [$^N variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5EN)